# Copy data, insert column and paste special formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheet where I am copying column and pasting it between certain columns. After that I am applying formula.

I have some misunderstanding in macro name, but it is basically adding and removing months. I have two buttons ADD and REMOVE. So using them I can add and remove months by one to/from the right. I need formulas for formulas to follow accordingly. First formula `=IF(C31=""January"",B30+IF(C31=""January"",1,0),B30)` is responsible for years counting, so after each January year is changing to next 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023 etc. Second formula is more simple for SUM.

Here is my current code for adding:

```
Sub Add_One_Year_CF()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lColumn As Long

    With CashflowSheet
        .Range("K:K").Copy
        .Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With

    lColumn = CashflowSheet.Cells(33, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    CashflowSheet.Range(Cells(30, 3), Cells(30, lColumn)).Formula = "=IF(C31=""January"",B30+IF(C31=""January"",1,0),B30)"
    CashflowSheet.Range(Cells(36, 3), Cells(36, lColumn)).Formula = "=C34+B36"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here is code for removing:

```
Sub Remove_One_Year_CF()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lc As Long

    With CashflowSheet
        lc = .Cells(30, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lc > 13 Then
            With .Range(.Cells(30, lc), .Cells(30, lc))
                .EntireColumn.Delete
            End With
        Else
            'msg no more columns to clear
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works fine for the first run. So if I am performing Add macro (for N times) it works, then I am performing Remove macro (until it stops in column 13). Then I am trying to perform Add again and after certain Add run I am starting to get errors in cells starting from column J.

[image]

What might be the problem?

P.S. There is data in row 30 (font color is just white)

---

**EDIT:**

I walked to another room and got an idea... what if my variable is wrong.

This is working solution. SJR was right about 33 and 30... That was the problem.

```
Sub Add_One_Year_CF()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CashflowSheet
        .Range("K:K").Copy
        .Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With

    CashflowSheet.Range(Cells(30, 3), Cells(30, CashflowSheet.Cells(30, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Formula = "=IF(C31=""January"",B30+IF(C31=""January"",1,0),B30)"
    CashflowSheet.Range(Cells(36, 3), Cells(36, CashflowSheet.Cells(36, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Formula = "=C34+B36"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What errors and on which lines? This needs full qualification `CashflowSheet.Range(Cells(30, 3), Cells(30, lColumn))`.

Comment: @SJR On my screenshot there are `#REF` errors starting from column J. This is after applying first ADD macro and then REMOVE macro.I guess I have some issue with applying formula after copying columns... but I can figure what exactly?

Comment: Your formula is probably referencing a cell which is later deleted.

Comment: Basically I need to apply this formula to new range after Adding or Deleting columns... Is there any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: I have condition `lc > 13` so it is not removing anything after M. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I suggest stepping through to see what's going on. Don't really understand what you're doing. Why do you base the last column on row 30 in one and row 33 in the other?

Comment: I am trying to apply two different formulas to two different ranges. Ranges are changing with adding and removing columns. First formula should be applied to range in row 30 after column 3 until last one on the right. Second formula should be applied to range in row 36 after column 3 until last one on the right. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out at me. Have you stepped through?

Comment: Btw why do you remove one column at a time?

Comment: I have some misunderstanding in macro name, but it is basically adding and removing months. I have two buttons ADD and REMOVE. So using them I can add and remove months by one to/from the right. I need formulas for formulas to follow accordingly. First formula is responsible for years counting, so after each January year is changing to next 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023 etc. Second formula is more simple for SUM.